# Can I login to Ubuntu server using Fingerprints

Tags: server, login, fingerprint-reader

Can I log in to my Ubuntu server using my fingerprint to authenticate. I have an HP pavilion dm4 with a fingerprint scanner built in I am using he laptop as a media server running Ubuntu Server 16 LTS and i am wondering if I can log in using the built in fingerprint scanner or maybe buying an external scanner to log in to the server.

Comment: You can google "Linux Fingerprint scanner" for many results including Ubuntu.

Comment: I am trying to use it with just the command line there is no GUI. I have been searching Google and have had no hits on anyone using it on just CLI or on Ubuntu server. I am reluctant to try using the regular guides to set it up because I don't want to be locked out of my machine.

Comment: Arch Linux (one of top search results) says to have password option when fingerprints go wonky.